# Print file name (after creating file)

Tags: python, file-handling, readfile

How can i display the name of the file (after creating it). for example
filename.....txt

```
from datetime import datetime
default_name_begining_of_the_file = "Investment_result_"

savereport = input("Save result to text file? ")

if savereport in ["y", "yes", "YES"]:

     nameoffileinput = (input("Name of begining of the file: ") or default_name_begining_of_the_file)
     generatedatetime = datetime.now().strftime("%Y_%m_%d-%I%M%S_%p")
     open(f'{nameoffileinput}_{generatedatetime}.txt', 'w')

else:
     print(f"Result will not be written to text file.")
```

Comment: Just add another `print(...)`?

Comment: Save `f'{nameoffileinput}_{generatedatetime}.txt'` to a variable.

Comment: yes, now i see it also, thanks

Answer (score 2):

Just add `print` before `open(f'{nameoffileinput}_{generatedatetime}.txt', 'w')`.

For example:

```
from datetime import datetime
default_name_begining_of_the_file = "Investment_result_"

savereport = input("Save result to text file? ")

if savereport in ["y", "yes", "YES"]:

     nameoffileinput = (input("Name of begining of the file: ") or default_name_begining_of_the_file)
     generatedatetime = datetime.now().strftime("%Y_%m_%d-%I%M%S_%p")
     file_name = f'{nameoffileinput}_{generatedatetime}.txt'
     print(f"The name of written file is : {file_name}")
     with open(file_name, 'w') as f:
        pass # do stuff...

else:
     print(f"Result will not be written to text file.")
```

Additionally, it would be better to close `open()` part with `with` statement.